# How to define routes for a large grid network in sumo?

Tags: sumo

When using SUMO to create a grid network, it seems we have to define route for different types of vehicles. But for a large grid network such as 10*10, it would be impossible to manually input the routes for different flow, especially when considering turning at intersections.

My goal is to have a large network, let flow run throught it with certain turning probabilities at intersections. Then I wish I could use traCI to control the signal lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways as to how you could manage multiple routes:

1. Define `trip` and/or `flow` with `to` edge and `from` edge attributes. The `DUAROUTER` application will find the shortest route possible or the best route possible (if `edge-weights` are provided)
2. The above (point 1) can also be achieved if `fromTaz/toTaz` (Traffic Assignment Zones) are assigned

**NOTE** - For both point 1 and 2, the `via` attribute can force the vehicles to travel through a given edge or a given set of edges.

3. Another way to generate multiple routes is to generate the 10*10 network and to note down (in the program) all the connections (this is done so that SUMO does not throw any `no connection` errors). A simple program can be written in conjunction with TraCI, that turns the vehicle from a given edge to a different edge on any junction. Given that this will be **time consuming**, but if your focus is not on the overall simulation time, this approach will be the most apt for you.
4. Another way is to add `rerouter` devices on all edges leading to a junction. You can define **new destinations and routes** here. This will be the easiest solution for a large network.

Comment: Thank you sir! I have a follow-up question. If my ultimate goal is to use traCI to control the traffic lights in such a large network, I need the network.xml and route.xml required by traCI.start. Does any of the above method can generate the necessary files for traCI?

Comment: I found netgenerator command in SUMO might be the easiest approach. You can just generate a network with one command line. netgenerate --grid --grid.number=10 --grid.length=400 --output-file=MySUMOFile.net.xml

Comment: If you have turning probabilities you should also look at the JTRRouter https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/JTRROUTER